# Uploading file with apollo/graphql to mongodb database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, file-upload, graphql, apollo

I want to upload file to mongodb databse with Apollo mutation.
Here's some of my config:
server.js(here's on port 4000):

```
...
// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  }) // Adding new mongo url parser
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = require('./modules/graphqlschemas/index');
const resolvers = require('./modules/resolvers/index');


// #5 Initialize an Apollo server
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    getUser: () =>  req.user,
    logout: () => {
      req.session = null;
      req.logout();
      return true
    }
  })
});
...
```

Now my schemas and resolvers:

graphqlschemas/image.js

```
module.exports = `
type File {
  _id: ID!
  path: String!
  filename: String!
  mimetype: String!
  encoding: String!
},

  type Query {
    uploads: [File]
  },

  type Mutation {
    singleUpload(file: Upload!): File!
  }
`;
```

resolvers/image.js( and here very important thing I've observed, file is always null there)

```
const Image = require('../../models/image');
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    uploads: (parent, args) => Image.find({}),
  },
  Mutation: {
    singleUpload: async (parent, {file}) => {
      console.log(file); // always null
    }
  }
}
```

, but let's go further to client( React app on port 3000):

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";

// const link = createUploadLink({ uri: '/graphql' });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    // Report errors to console in a user friendly format
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
          )
        );
      if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }),
    createUploadLink({
      uri: '/graphql'
    })
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

mutation query( I am using codgen to generate graphql hooks):

```
mutation SingleUpload($file: Upload!) {
  singleUpload(file: $file) {
    _id
    filename
  }
}
```

And file uploading with component(most important lines):

```
const [fileData, setFileData] = useState(null);

const [singleUpload] = useSingleUploadMutation();


  const onChangeFile = e => {
    setFileData(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  console.log(fileData);
  const onChangeText = e => {
    setNewsData({
      ...newsData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  const onSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await singleUpload({ variables: { file: fileData  } }); 
  }


return (

<form id="addNews" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input id="news" type="file" name="news" placeholder="Add photo" onChange={onChangeFile} />                                                                             
            </div>
<div className="form-group mt-4 mb-0">
     <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Add photo"/>
</div>
</form>
)
```

fileData looks like that:
[image: file]

,but in resolver is equal null, so maybe that is the problem?

Comment: It is not clear why you are wrapping with `variables`.  `await singleUpload({ variables: { file: fileData  } }); `.  I think an easy debugging check would be to slightly change your resolver to not destructure the argument and log that out. `singleUpload: async (parent, logThisArg) => {`

Comment: I did that many times. It gives me:  file: {}

Comment: take it separately server uploading works? tested with postman - multipart/form? after postman test - check if react request body is the same/compare them detaily

Answer (score 0):

On graphql playground surely I get a problem, because I pass a string, but I also get this one:

> "...‘Upload’ scalar literal unsupported."
> It's weird, because I read that if I don't use makeExecutableSchema, apollo server should set it without any extra code. Is something changed there?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It seems that apollo-boost package doesn't support uploading files.
I changed:

> import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";

on

> import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";